# Spring Integration: How to use an "error gateway" with Splitter Aggregator when Exception thrown

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration, gateway

I've seen more than a few posts about this topic, but can't seem to find a solution to my specific problem, which I think is a pretty typical one, namely: how to keep processing messages when an error occurs (Exception thrown) using a Splitter / Aggregator.

The best explanation that I have come upon is [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/129704-error-handling-aggregator-and-response-problems). But there's no explanation of exactly what/how the filters/transformers work. And in the end, the author posts "That worked!" but without posting an updated SI.config.xml.

From what I understand, the idea is to use an "error gateway", which is downstream from the original calling gateway and after the Splitter. This Gateway's job would be if there is an Exception thrown, to deal with it, but to make sure (via a transformer or a filter) that all Messages make it to the Aggregator.

My very simplified SI.config.xml if more or less like this:

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" ... /> // incoming gateway
<int:chain ... input-channel="in" output-channel="out">
  <int:splitter ... />
  <int:service-activator />
  <int:aggregator />
</int:chain>
```

So my question is, where exactly to stick this other gateway? And how to configure filters/transformers that (from what I gather) would grab the Message which launched an Exception and put it back on the correct channel (after logging it or whatever ...) so all Messages make it to the Aggregator.

I have looked at the SI samples, on SO, and the 2 SI books (SI in Acton and Pro SI) and can't find an example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution looks like:

```
<int:chain ... input-channel="in" output-channel="out">
  <int:splitter ... />
  <int:gateway request-channel="processChannel" errorChannel="processError"/>
  <int:aggregator />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="processChannel">
  <int:service-activator />
</int:chain>
```

The `error handler` on the `processError` channel should consult incoming `ErrorMessage` and returns some compensation which will be sent to the `aggregator`.

The `ErrorMessage` typically contains `MessagingException` with a `failedMessage` where error has caused. That `failedMessage` contains all useful headers to go ahead with a compensation. Some of them are `replyChannel` and `errorChannel`, but for your `aggregator` case you need all those `correlationId`, `sequenceNumber`, `sequenceSize` etc. In other words when you build compensation message to be sent forward to the downstream for the `aggregator`, you should copy all the `headers` from that `failedMessage`.

For more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying. I didn't get that it was so "easy", I hadn't ever seen an example like this. It makes perfect sense, but I don't think I would ever have discovered it on my own; it's almost as if you are "gratuitously" adding a gateway in the middle of the chain, when you could simply use a service-activator. But of course, using a gateway allows you do define an error channel ... and of course you can then add a handler / service-activator to deal with the Exception, and then add the headers so the flow continues to the aggregator. Many, many thanks!

Comment: You can find something similar in the reference manual http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain, where we talk about chain from chain

Comment: Right you are, the exact use case is discussed under "Calling a Chain from within a Chain". I hadn't looked at that section very closely because I didn't think that's what I needed to do in order to use an "error gateway". But yes, it is well explained there. Thanks!